# Thermostat wiring( honeywell t6360b

Tags: wiring, thermostat

trying to install a new thermostat but I can't get it to work.

In the pics you can see the old setup and diagram and the new diagram.

From that I understand I should connect brown to 1, blue to 2,and yello/green to ground but that doesn't seem to work.

Any thoughts?
[image: old setup]
[image: old diagram]
[image: new diagram]

Comment: It appears that the old has a ground wire (green-striped yellow)  doing something that is not ground (and that's virtually always a violation of applicable code, wherever it is located, and applying black tape does not remove the violation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like

1. old 1 is new 1
2. old 2 is new 3
3. old 3 is new 4
4. old 4 is new 2

The ground wire appears to have been repurposed as the switched output, which is almost always a code violation, so using the ground wire as it was used probably continues to be a code violation (anywhere with code, basically) and using a ground terminal on the new stat that the old 'stat lacks would be expected not to work correctly if that's how it's being used.

If the new 'stat is supposed to be grounded you'll need a new cable with more wires in it. And if you want to not be in violation of applicable code, if any, the same.